# How to change excel workbook orientation and papersize (vb.net)

Tags: excel, vb.net

I need to convert a VBA script to vb.net using Visual Studio 2017. The original script is:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA3
End With
```

The code I tried in vb.net is:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

...

```
With MonthSheet.PageSetup
    .Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape
    .PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA3
End With
```

Where the "MonthSheet" refers to one of the workbooks of the opened excel file. This code (however compiles) seems to delete all the workbooks of the excel file.

How can I change the orientation and papersize of an excel sheet from vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

See this link for changing the [Paper Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.papersize).

For changing the orientation of Excel Workbook.

```
xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape
```

Comment: I have imported the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel at the beginning of my code. Sorry for not mentioning it eariler, I have updated to original post.

Answer (score 0):

The code I wrote was correct, it didnt work because of a programming error in a different subroutine.